# Oracle : :punct: character class is matching Pound Symbol and returns true as a match. Pound is not a punctuation character. Why it is still matching?

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-like

Below query returns x in Oracle

select 'x'
from dual where **regexp_like**('regex1,£','^[a-zA-Z0-9[:**punct**:]]+$');

As per my understanding it should fail to match as, £ is not a punctuation character .

Comment: POSIX `[:punct:]` character class matches both punctuation and symbols.

Comment: If you want to only match ASCII punctuation proper, use `^[][!-#%-*,-/\\:;?@-_{}a-zA-Z0-9]+$`